# Unity - Water Cube (to 2D game)

Tags: unity, shaders, water, materials, cubemap

I wonder if you can create a cube of water within the unity!

I'm starting to use the Unity, and took a sought as to whether there was already something like this ... but have not found any tutorial

The idea is to use the 3D feature of water and turn it into a 2D scenario:

As shown below:

[image]

[image]

[image]

For this result:

[image]

The idea would be to make the cube of the material is "water".

Its possible?

Comment: Do you mean to say creating realistic physics-based water? from the references you posted, it seems you are trying to create 3D Water, there are lot many different ways to create water in Unity, could you please elaborate more on what you want to do?

Answer (score -1):

This is achievable , what you need is Unity water and some script to simulate buoyancy.

You can find the script in this link:-
http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/buoyancy-script.72974/

Note:- You might also need to use some particles or mesh to fill the volume of the water. As unity water is restricted only to the surface and not the entire volume :)

Comment: Hi thanks for this comment! I have no idea how to do it. lol

Answer (score -1):

It's definitely achievable. Having never attempted it or anything, or really even tried all I could find was this [link.](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/creating-water-cubes.288185/) I'm hoping it'll help you, as I look forward to trying it.

Comment: Please do not post answers which do not contain any useful information except for a link to another website. At least summarize the content of the link in your own words instead. For more information, please read the question ["Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers) on meta-stackexchange.